# Embedding FreeCAD in python script

Tags: python, embedding, freecad

I am trying to run FreeCAD modules from a python script. Here is the code I have written to import the FreeCAD modules according with [this tutorial](http://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/index.php?title=Embedding_FreeCAD)" (eventhoug I don't have any FreeCAD.dll installed on my HD):

```
FREECADPATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FreeCAD 0.16\\bin"
import sys
sys.path.append(FREECADPATH)

import FreeCAD
import Part
import Mesh
...then the FreeCAD commands
```

But i got the following error:

> " import Part 
>   ImportError: No module named Part"

I also tried with a 64bit version of the FreeCAD

> C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.16\bin

Any suggestion?

Comment: can you list the contents of `C:\\Program Files\\Program Files (x86)\\bin` in the question ? it is possible that you need a 64-bit version of python to load a 64 bit DLL.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry there was a typo in the question (wrong folder). Do you mean all the file contained in the folders?

Comment: So `import FreeCAD` was fine and only `Part` gave an error?